# How to create a model for data something like this?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

How to create a model for data something like this. Can someone tell me how to create `products[]` and some child elements inside this array in my **model.ts** file?

I need help with initializing this **model.ts** constructor.

```
private _data: Video[] = [
    new Video('Family', new Result(44, 'abc', 'https://cleantechnica.com/files/2017/10/rimac.jpg')),
    new Video('Family', new Result(43, 'abc1', 'https://cleantechnica.com/files/2017/10/rimac.jpg')),
    new Video('Family', new Result(42, 'abc2', 'https://cleantechnica.com/files/2017/10/rimac.jpg')),
    new Video('Family', new Result(41, 'abc3', 'https://cleantechnica.com/files/2017/10/rimac.jpg'))
];
```

The below one is **model.ts** file

```
export class Result {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public imageUrl: string) {}
}
```

```
import {Result} from './res.model';

export class Video {
    constructor(
        public category: string,
        public results: Result
        ) {}
}
```

In my **services.ts** page I want to initialize new elements with the help of **model.ts** file constructor.

Comment: You're mixing a type definition with a constructor definition. Start by defining your types: what is a Video, what is a Product. Then decide what the caller should provide when constructing a Product (that would be the arguments of the Product class). Then decide what the caller should provide when constructing a Video (that would be the arguments of the Video constructor).

Comment: @JBNizet basically iam creating a video class which has category(Action, Drama, Family etc) which should be a array and this array has inturn 3 more objects id, name,url...................i am facing problem to create a model for such data

Comment: Assuming `_data` is an array of videos, it thus contains objects of type Video. That's your first type. Each video in this array has a category (of type string), an expandd flag (of type boolean), and an array, named products, of objects. I thus deduce that every object in this array is a Product. So you should define a type for these objects, named Product. A Product has an id of type number, a name of type string, and an imageUrl of type string. Once you have defined this type, you can then say that the type of the products field of the Video class is Array<Product>.

Comment: Iam new to typeScript so @JBNizet can please post the modified code for me...that would be great

Comment: I'm trying to explain how to do that by yourself. Why don't you at least try to write a Product class (or interface), and then a Video class (or interface), based on what I explained? Without any constructor, at least at first.

Comment: Here _data array is hardcoded and i dont want to do this instead i want call this video class constructor ( new Video(...)) and create the products

Comment: Before calling a constructor for a class, you need to properly define this class, and the classes that is uses: Video, and Product. So try to do that first. 1. What is the structure of my objects: that's the class/interface definitions. 2. How do I construct such a structure: that's the constructor definition. 3. Construct an object: that's calling the constructors. You're trying to do 3 before having done 1 and 2. Start with 1.

Comment: @JBNizet i made some changes ...can you check them out

Comment: That's better. But you changed your model compared to the previous version of your question, where ech each video had **several** products, not just one. So if you still want that, you need  an **array** of Result in Video.

Comment: yaya exactly how to do that...........each object should have array of results

Comment: `public results: Result[]` or `public results: Array<Result>`. I'm confused: you already know about arrays since you declare and create an array of videos.

Comment: ya i know the concept but iam confused where to create this result array

Comment: You would create it the exact same way you're creating the array of videos: `[new Result(...), new Result(...), ...]`